# Firebase OrderByChild Timestamp not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a datepicker to retrieve an object from my Firebase DB, it works but no matter which date I select, today's object is returned.

I am using `orderByChild` and timestamp to sort, but it is not working.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref(uid);
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(strDateTime).endAt(strDateTime + "86400").on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        // childData will be the actual contents of the child
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        arms = childData.arms;
        console.log(arms);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arms;
    });
});
```

My database structure is:

```
{
  "ZwYo0nB92oODcjjxJ0Eqeo4l3Ny1" : {
    "BodyStats-KaFX2MvLHt0U6lLc365" : {
      "arms" : "48",
      "bodyfat" : "",
      "calves" : "",
      "chest" : "",
      "forearms" : "",
      "hips" : "",
      "neck" : "",
      "shoulders" : "",
      "thighs" : "",
      "timestamp" : 1484188562973,
      "waist" : "",
      "weight" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

The strDateTime:

```
// Date Picker Function
var strDateTime;
var timeInt;
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: false, // Expanded cal
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "img/calendar-icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function () { // When cal is opened execute
            var currentDate = new Date($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
            var strDateTime = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
            alert(strDateTime);
            startDatabaseQueries(strDateTime);
            var timeInt = parseInt(strDateTime); // Parse strDateTime for startDatabaseQueries function
        }
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    var currentDate = new Date($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
    var strDateTime = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
});
```

Comment: The timestamp in the database is a number and you appear to be using strings for `startAt`, etc. And concatenating `"86400"` doesn't make much sense. And the timestamps are in milliseconds, so you should be adding 86,400,000 for 24 hours.

Comment: @cartant Would it be better to just get a date from a datepicker (instead of using a timestamp) and updating my database to have a date variable?

Comment: The timestamp in the database is fine, just query it using numeric timestamps (that is, if you have a `Date` instance, call `getTime` to obtain the timestamp). Presumably, the date picker is able to give you a `Date` instance.

Comment: @cartant I am not completely tracking sorry. If I have my --ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(strDateTime).endAt(strDateTime + "86400").on('value', function (snapshot) { -- method, how could I pass a timestamp variable using JQuery Datepicker?

Comment: I don't know anything about that picker, but you just need to get a JavaScript `Date` and call [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on it and pass that value to `startAt`, etc.

Comment: @cartant I understand thank you! Would I need to add anything to endAt? The logic is escaping me

Comment: @cartant Quick question, would it be easier to use equalTo()?

Comment: If you have the starting timestamp as a string, you can convert it to a number and do your arithmetic on that: `var timeInt = parseInt(strDateTime); ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(timeInt).endAt(timeInt + 86400)`. But it will be a lot easier to help if you show us where `strDateTime` comes from or (even better) show the problem with a hard-coded value for `strDateTime`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I use the timeInt method, the date is returned in the same manner as strDateTime for example 11/1/17, without quotes. I will edit my post for the strDatTime code.